# What is the effect of placing the commit after DML in procedure?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created a procedure in a package which is doing insert/delete in the table and after successful transaction, commit is done.

like this:

```
create or replace package pac is    
procedure pr_test(emp_id number)
is
begin
-- some code
if something then
  insert
else
  delete

commit;
end pr_test;
end pac ;
```

Should I make this transaction as AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION? What is the effect of placing the commit like this in program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the effect of placing the commit like this in program?

The [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_4010.htm) describes `COMMIT` as:

> **Purpose**
>
> Use the `COMMIT` statement to end your current transaction and make
>   permanent all changes performed in the transaction. A transaction is a
>   sequence of SQL statements that Oracle Database treats as a single
>   unit. This statement also erases all savepoints in the transaction and
>   releases transaction locks.

If you have three `PROCEDURE` and each one contains a `COMMIT` statement then you cannot run all three then, if an exception occurs in a latter one, `ROLLBACK` them all as the changes from the first two will already be `COMMIT`ted.

As a general rule, you should **not** use `COMMIT` in a `PROCEDURE` or `FUNCTION` but should leave it up to the caller to `COMMIT` the transaction so they can bundle multiple actions together.

There are, of course, use cases where you will want to violate this rule but you should consider each case separately and take time to fully understand your business logic before you break this rule so you know what is `COMMIT`ted in each instance.

> Should I make this transaction as `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`?

One use-case is logging - you may have a `PROCEDURE` which calls another `PROCEDURE` to log the user's actions and, regardless of whether the initial action succeeds or fails you want to keep a log of the action and ensure that log is `COMMIT`ted. In this case, the logging `PROCEDURE` should be an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` and contain a `COMMIT` statement and the calling statement should (probably) have neither.

So, if the `COMMIT` of one `PROCEDURE` is always required and is independent of whether the caller `COMMIT`s other data then make the `PROCEDURE` an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`. If the `PROCEDURE`s can be bundled together and then `ROLLBACK` as a group then you do not want to make them `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`s.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do. If you want the procedure to be a stand-alone transaction then I would recommend adding `pragma autonomous_transaction`.

Ex: First scenario

1. update table 1
2. pragma autonomous_transaction - >update table 2 -> commit
3. rollback

table 2 will be commited and table 1 will be rolled back

Ex: Second scenario

1. Update table 1
2. update table 2 -> commit
3. rollback

both table 1 and 2 will be commited cause it treats it as one transaction

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to refer this article. It will clarify your queries.

[AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](http://www.asktheoracle.net/what-is-the-pragma-autonomous_transaction-in-plsql.html)

The pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION instructs the compiler to treat the pl/sql block following the pragma as autonomous (independent) from the calling transaction.

Should you make it Autonomous transaction solely depend upon the criteria of usage. In both the ways COMMIT has to be placed inside.

Below example will illustrate it clearly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE testav
AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; --Declaring is Autonomous Transaction.
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO testa VALUES
    ('1','2',sysdate
    );
    commit;
END;

DECLARE
  lv_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  testav; -- Calling the Procedure
  lv_num:=to_number('av'); --This will fail to parse but the procedure call will be successfull even though the calling block has failed.
END;
```

/

Comment: This is a link-only answer. It would be better to include the relevant points from the linked article in the answer.

Comment: Also, autonomous transactions are easy to misuse. You should not advise people to use them unless you know they have an appropriate scenario. That's not the case here.