# Can I rollback after calling stored procedure in java test?

Tags: java, oracle, transactions

I have method in DAO layer which call stored procedure in Oracle database:

```
@Override
public void deleteNode(Integer nodeId) {
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("nodeId",nodeId)
            .addValue("user", "DUMMY");

    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(ebDataSource)
            .withSchemaName("SCHEMA")
            .withCatalogName("PK_GRAPH_DML")
            .withProcedureName("DeleteNode");

    simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
}
```

And I have to test this method. But I want to rollback all changes after every execution of this test.

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback
public void deleteEBNode_ok() {
    Integer nodeId = 5714;

    ebFlowService.deleteEBNode(nodeId.toString());

    EBFlowToolSelect nodeModelFromDatabase = ebFlowService.getNodeById(nodeId);
    Assert.assertNull(nodeModelFromDatabase.getNodeId());
}
```

I tried to annotate my test by `@Transactional` and `@Rollback`, but it didn't help.
Is it possible to make my test rollback all changes that were made by stored procedure?

Comment: That depends on the stored procedure. If that manages its own transaction there isn't much you can do, else it should participate in a transaction and `@Transactional` on the test method should be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the stored procedure.

- If the stored procedure contains a [`COMMIT` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998025/what-is-the-effect-of-placing-the-commit-after-dml-in-procedure/41998936#41998936) then you will only be able to rollback any actions taken after this statement.
- If the stored procedure is an [autonomous transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) then it will be independent of your transaction (and contain its own `COMMIT` statement) and you cannot roll it back.

If the stored procedure contains no `COMMIT` statement and is not autonomous then you should be able to roll it back.