# How to solve Oracle Subscript beyond count error when inserting data from arrays?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have developed a stored procedure like this :

```
        create or replace 
        PROCEDURE PROC_INS (
              GB_LD_ID   IN NUMBER,
              GB_CS_SP       IN TBL_CHAR,
              GB_UF_NMS    IN TBL_CHAR,
              GB_RW_BRS   IN TBL_NBR,
              GB_RT_SMS       IN TBL_CHAR,
              GB_LC_SD     IN TBL_CHAR)
        AS

          LV_ERROR   NUMBER(10);
          LV_MESSAGE varchar2(512);
          LV_TM_DI NUMBER(19);

        BEGIN


        select max(ID) into LV_TM_DI from TME_TAB;
        if(LV_TM_DI  IS NULL)THEN
           LV_TM_DI:=0;
        end if;

          FOR i IN GB_RW_BRS.FIRST..GB_RW_BRS.LAST
          LOOP
            BEGIN
              Insert into TME_TAB (ID,VS,PUCS,DT_CRD,NGL_ID,NAME,UD_DT,RW_NHG,TRF_SM,LS_FD)
              Values((LV_TM_DI+1),0,GB_CS_SP(i),SYSTIMESTAMP,GB_LD_ID,GB_UF_NMS(i),SYSTIMESTAMP,GB_RW_BRS(i),GB_RT_SMS(i),GB_LC_SD(i));
            END;
            LV_TM_DI := LV_TM_DI + 1;
          END LOOP;
          COMMIT;


        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           IF(LV_MESSAGE IS NULL) THEN
            LV_ERROR    :=-20004;
            LV_MESSAGE  :=SQLERRM;
          END IF;
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (LV_ERROR,LV_MESSAGE);

        END PROC_INS;
```

This procedure inserts records by reading arrays of type `TBL_CHAR` and `TBL_NBR`. 
`TBL_CHAR` is defined as below :

```
create or replace TYPE "TBL_CHAR" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
```

But while the insertion runs I get this error : `ORA-20004: ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count` .

Can some one please help me out here  ?

Comment: All these TBL_CHAR, TBL_NBR,  TBL_CHAR array size are same? Assume GB_RW_BRS size 10 but GB_CS_SP is 7 then it may throw error like this when you process 8 record in GB_RW_BRS

Comment: @Gaj . They will be of same  size .

Comment: if possible use extend and then try to insert

Comment: Can you give example call to your procedure (one that causes this error to raise)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like arrays have different number of elements. My test:

```
create or replace type tbl_char as table of varchar2(100);
create or replace type tbl_nbr as table of number;
create table tme_tab(id number(3), nbr number(5), chr varchar2(100));

create or replace procedure proc_ins ( i_id in number, i_nbr in tbl_nbr, i_chr in tbl_char ) as
    lv_tm_di number(6);
begin
    select nvl(max(ID), 0) into lv_tm_di from tme_tab;

    for i in i_nbr.first..i_nbr.last loop
        lv_tm_di := lv_tm_di + 1;
        begin
            insert into tme_tab (id, nbr, chr) values(lv_tm_di, i_nbr(i), i_chr(i));
        end;
    end loop;
end proc_ins;
```

... and this works:

```
begin 
    proc_ins(1, tbl_nbr(1, 7, 0), tbl_char('P', 'Q', 'R'));
end;
```

... and this does not work (ORA-06533):

```
begin 
    proc_ins(1, tbl_nbr(1, 7, 0, 9), tbl_char('P', 'Q', 'R'));
end;
```

Check size before inserting and throw exception:

```
    if i_nbr.count <> i_chr.count then
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'wrong array dimmensions');
    end if;
```

Or insert nulls for shorter array. Also your procedure uses counter when generating Id, consider using sequence instead, important for concurrent updates.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a `SEQUENCE` to get the unique IDs (rather than `MAX`).
- [Don't `COMMIT` in the procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41998936/1509264), do that from the calling block as it lets you perform multiple DML operations in a transaction and then roll them all back if there is an issue.
- Find the `LEAST` number of entries in the collections and only insert that many rows.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc63ca/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TME_TAB (
  ID int,
  VS int,
  PUCS char(100),
  DT_CRD timestamp,
  NGL_ID number,
  NAME char(100),
  UD_DT timestamp,
  RW_NHG number,
  TRF_SM char(100),
  LS_FD char(100)
)
/

CREATE TYPE TBL_CHAR IS TABLE OF CHAR(100)
/
CREATE TYPE TBL_NBR IS TABLE OF NUMBER
/

CREATE SEQUENCE TME_TAB__ID__SEQ
/

create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_INS (
  GB_LD_ID  IN NUMBER,
  GB_CS_SP  IN TBL_CHAR,
  GB_UF_NMS IN TBL_CHAR,
  GB_RW_BRS IN TBL_NBR,
  GB_RT_SMS IN TBL_CHAR,
  GB_LC_SD  IN TBL_CHAR)
AS
  LV_ERROR   NUMBER(10);
  LV_MESSAGE varchar2(512);
  LV_TM_DI NUMBER(19);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. LEAST(
                  GB_CS_SP.COUNT,
                  GB_UF_NMS.COUNT,
                  GB_RW_BRS.COUNT,
                  GB_RT_SMS.COUNT,
                  GB_LC_SD.COUNT
                )
  LOOP
    Insert into TME_TAB (
      ID,            VS,           PUCS,         DT_CRD,
      NGL_ID,        NAME,         UD_DT,        RW_NHG,
      TRF_SM,        LS_FD
    ) Values(
      TME_TAB__ID__SEQ.NEXTVAL,  0, GB_CS_SP(i),  SYSTIMESTAMP,
      GB_LD_ID,      GB_UF_NMS(i), SYSTIMESTAMP, GB_RW_BRS(i),
      GB_RT_SMS(i),  GB_LC_SD(i)
    );
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF(LV_MESSAGE IS NULL) THEN
      LV_ERROR    :=-20004;
      LV_MESSAGE  :=SQLERRM;
    END IF;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (LV_ERROR,LV_MESSAGE);
END PROC_INS;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
BEGIN
  PROC_INS (
    GB_LD_ID  => 1,
    GB_CS_SP  => TBL_CHAR( 'sp_a', 'sp_b' ),
    GB_UF_NMS => TBL_CHAR( 'nms_a', 'nms_b' ),
    GB_RW_BRS => TBL_NBR( 1.1, 1.2 ),
    GB_RT_SMS => TBL_CHAR( 'sms_a', 'sms_b' ),
    GB_LC_SD  => TBL_CHAR( 'sd_a', 'sd_b' )
  );
  COMMIT;
END;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc63ca/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM TME_TAB
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc63ca/1/1)**:

```
| ID | VS |                                                                                                 PUCS |                     DT_CRD | NGL_ID |                                                                                                 NAME |                      UD_DT | RW_NHG |                                                                                               TRF_SM |                                                                                                LS_FD |
|----|----|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------|--------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------|--------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |  0 | sp_a                                                                                                 | 2018-07-18 11:07:31.827742 |      1 | nms_a                                                                                                | 2018-07-18 11:07:31.827742 |    1.1 | sms_a                                                                                                | sd_a                                                                                                 |
|  2 |  0 | sp_b                                                                                                 | 2018-07-18 11:07:31.828545 |      1 | nms_b                                                                                                | 2018-07-18 11:07:31.828545 |    1.2 | sms_b                                                                                                | sd_b                                                                                                 |
```