# ORA-00928: Getting multiple errors while passing XML in stored procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures

I am inserting data into table using `XML` like below:

```
PROCEDURE insert_expt_excel(strxml  IN xmltype
                           ,poutmsg OUT NVARCHAR2)

 AS
  cnt NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

  /* after update, delete query */
  FOR tmmapping IN (SELECT strxml.extract('excelData/R4GSTATE/text()').getstringval() AS r4gstate
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/POLITICAL_STATE_NAME/text()').getstringval() AS political_state_name
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/POLITICAL_STATE_CODE/text()').getstringval() AS political_state_code
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/CMP/text()').getstringval() AS cmp
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/SAP_ID/text()').getstringval() AS sap_id
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/SITE_NAME/text()').getstringval() AS site_name
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/RFCDATE/text()').getstringval() AS rfcdate
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/RFS_DATE/text()').getstringval() AS rfs_date
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/RFE1_DATE/text()').getstringval() AS rfe1_date
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/SITE_DROP_DATE/text()').getstringval() AS site_drop_date
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/INFRA_PROVIDER/text()').getstringval() AS infra_provider
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/IP_COLO_SITEID/text()').getstringval() AS ip_colo_siteid
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/VENDOR_CODE/text()').getstringval() AS vendor_code
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/MW_INSTALLED/text()').getstringval() AS mw_installed
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/DG_NONDG/text()').getstringval() AS dg_nondg
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/EB_NONEB/text()').getstringval() AS eb_noneb
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/TOWER_TYPE/text()').getstringval() AS tower_type
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE/text()').getstringval() AS id_od_countchange
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE/text()').getstringval() AS id_od_changeddate
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE/text()').getstringval() AS tenancy_countchange
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE/text()').getstringval() AS tenancy_changeddate
                      FROM TABLE(xmlsequence(strxml.extract('NewDataSet/excelData'))) strxml)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO tbl_ipcolo_billing_mst
      (cmp, sap_id, id_od_countchange, id_od_changeddate, rrh_countchange,
       rrh_changeddate, tenancy_countchange, tenancy_changeddate, rfs_date,
       rfe1_date, infra_provider, ip_colo_siteid, site_name, r4gstate,
       mw_installed, dg_nondg, eb_noneb, tower_type, vendor_code, rfcdate,
       political_state_name, political_state_code, site_drop_date)
    VALUES
      (tmmapping.cmp, tmmapping.sap_id, tmmapping.id_od_countchange,
       tmmapping.id_od_changeddate, tmmapping.rrh_countchange,
       tmmapping.rrh_changeddate, tmmapping.tenancy_countchange,
       tmmapping.tenancy_changeddate, tmmapping.rfs_date, tmmapping.rfe1_date,
       tmmapping.infra_provider, tmmapping.ip_colo_siteid, tmmapping.site_name,
       tmmapping.r4gstate, tmmapping.mw_installed, tmmapping.dg_nondg,
       tmmapping.eb_noneb, tmmapping.tower_type, tmmapping.vendor_code,
       tmmapping.rfcdate, tmmapping.political_state_name,
       tmmapping.political_state_code, tmmapping.site_drop_date);
  END LOOP;

  cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  IF (cnt > 0)
  THEN
    BEGIN
      COMMIT;
      poutmsg := '1';
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      poutmsg := '0';

    END;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;

    poutmsg := '0';

END insert_expt_excel;
```

But I am getting error as:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 28, column 24:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "STRXML"."EXTRACT": invalid identifier
> ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> ORA-06550: line 81, column 2:
> PLS-00364: loop index variable 'TMMAPPING' use is invalid
> ORA-06550: line 81, column 12:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
> ORA-06550: line 31, column 1:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> ORA-06550: line 85, column 1:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'CNT' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 85, column 1:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ORA-06550: line 87, column 4:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'CNT' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 87, column 1:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

Comment: I don't see the error mentioned in the title in your question.

Comment: @Rene: there are multiple errors coming so I described that in my post

Comment: Describe what you want to do, the steps taken and the errors that you get. The piece of code you provide can't possibly be all.

Comment: @Rene: I want to insert my record in the table using `xml`. I have written the stored procedure for the same. But due to above mentioned error i am unable to do it. I have updated it with proper errors now

Comment: A good approach is to try to minimize the example while preserving the error. Could you observe the same behavior with two EXTRACTs instead of 21? Then use the saved space to post data to make the example reproducible. You may also try to switch to a `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of using INSERT is a `cursor loop`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber" `ORA-06550: line 9, column 24:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "STRXML"."EXTRACT": invalid identifier` and `PLS-00364: loop index variable 'TMMAPPING' use is invalid` are still coming with 2 extracts.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: Can you pls let me know how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XMLTABLE`:

**Procedure**:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_expt_excel(
  strxml  IN xmltype,
  poutmsg OUT NVARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_ipcolo_billing_mst (
    cmp,
    sap_id,
    id_od_countchange,
    id_od_changeddate,
    rrh_countchange,
    rrh_changeddate,
    tenancy_countchange,
    tenancy_changeddate,
    rfs_date,
    rfe1_date,
    infra_provider,
    ip_colo_siteid,
    site_name,
    r4gstate,
    mw_installed,
    dg_nondg,
    eb_noneb,
    tower_type,
    vendor_code,
    rfcdate,
    political_state_name,
    political_state_code,
    site_drop_date
  )
  SELECT cmp,
         sap_id,
         id_od_countchange,
         id_od_changeddate,
         NULL AS rrh_countchange,
         NULL AS rrh_changeddate,
         tenancy_countchange,
         tenancy_changeddate,
         rfs_date,
         rfe1_date,
         infra_provider,
         ip_colo_siteid,
         site_name,
         r4gstate,
         mw_installed,
         dg_nondg,
         eb_noneb,
         tower_type,
         vendor_code,
         rfcdate,
         political_state_name,
         political_state_code,
         site_drop_date
  FROM   XMLTABLE(
           '//NewDataSet/excelData'
           PASSING strxml
           COLUMNS cmp                  VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './CMP',
                   sap_id               VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './SAP_ID',
                   id_od_countchange    VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE',
                   id_od_changeddate    DATE           PATH './ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE',
                   tenancy_countchange  VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE',
                   tenancy_changeddate  DATE           PATH './TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE',
                   rfs_date             DATE           PATH './RFS_DATE',
                   rfe1_date            DATE           PATH './RFE1_DATE',
                   infra_provider       VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './INFRA_PROVIDER',
                   ip_colo_siteid       VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './IP_COLO_SITEID',
                   site_name            VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './SITE_NAME',
                   r4gstate             VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './R4GSTATE',
                   mw_installed         VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './MW_INSTALLED',
                   dg_nondg             VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './DG_NONDG',
                   eb_noneb             VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './EB_NONEB',
                   tower_type           VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './TOWER_TYPE',
                   vendor_code          VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './VENDOR_CODE',
                   rfcdate              DATE           PATH './RFCDATE',
                   political_state_name VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './POLITICAL_STATE_NAME',
                   political_state_code VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './POLITICAL_STATE_CODE',
                   site_drop_date       DATE           PATH './SITE_DROP_DATE'
         );

  IF ( SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 ) THEN
    poutmsg := '1';
  ELSE
    poutmsg := '0';
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    poutmsg := '0';
END insert_expt_excel;
/
```

You will need to update it to the appropriate data types. `rrh_countchange` and `rrh_changeddate` are not in your `SELECT` statement.

Some other points:

- Don't use `OTHERS` to catch all exceptions; instead catch specific expected exceptions and if an unexpected exception occurs then you are able to see that it has occurred and debug the issue rather than just silently hiding it.
- [Don't use `COMMIT` in the stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998025/what-is-the-effect-of-placing-the-commit-after-dml-in-procedure/41998936#41998936); instead use it in the calling block so you can chain multiple stored procedures and `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` them all as a single transaction.

**Call it**:

```sql
DECLARE
  success NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  insert_expt_excel( XMLType( '<NewDataSet>
  <excelData>
    <CMP>abc</CMP>
    <SAP_ID>def</SAP_ID>
    <ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE>ghi</ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE>
    <ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE>2019-09-30</ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE>
  </excelData>
</NewDataSet>' ), success );
  IF success = 1 THEN
    COMMIT;
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_ipcolo_billing_mst;
```

> ```
> CMP | SAP_ID | ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE | ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE | RRH_COUNTCHANGE | RRH_CHANGEDDATE | TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE | TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE | RFS_DATE | RFE1_DATE | INFRA_PROVIDER | IP_COLO_SITEID | SITE_NAME | R4GSTATE | MW_INSTALLED | DG_NONDG | EB_NONEB | TOWER_TYPE | VENDOR_CODE | RFCDATE | POLITICAL_STATE_NAME | POLITICAL_STATE_CODE | SITE_DROP_DATE
> :-- | :----- | :---------------- | :---------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------- | :-------- | :------------- | :------------- | :-------- | :------- | :----------- | :------- | :------- | :--------- | :---------- | :------ | :------------------- | :------------------- | :-------------
> abc | def    | ghi               | 30-SEP-19         | null            | null            | null                | null                | null     | null      | null           | null           | null      | null     | null         | null     | null     | null       | null        | null    | null                 | null                 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87c56ec139b690c4924fbbef82c53ff8)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer MT0, `extract()`  wont work ?

Comment: `EXTRACT` would work but it is [deprecated in Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions068.htm#SQLRF00640) so you should be using `XMLQUERY` or `XMLTABLE` instead as these are going to continue being supported in future versions.

Comment: I added two more field like below `rrh_countchange  VARCHAR2(4000) PATH './RRH_COUNTCHANGE',
                   rrh_changeddate  DATE           PATH './RRH_CHANGEDDATE'` but got error while compiling it after `ALTER` as `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"`

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the errors you get by trying to run your code exactly as posted.

Missing is either the package the procedure is part of or a "create or replace" in front of it.
With the insert statement removed (I don't have the table) this code compiles.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_expt_excel(strxml  IN xmltype
                           ,poutmsg OUT NVARCHAR2)

 AS
  cnt NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

  /* after update, delete query */
  FOR tmmapping IN (SELECT strxml.extract('excelData/R4GSTATE/text()').getstringval() AS r4gstate
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/POLITICAL_STATE_NAME/text()').getstringval() AS political_state_name
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/POLITICAL_STATE_CODE/text()').getstringval() AS political_state_code
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/CMP/text()').getstringval() AS cmp
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/SAP_ID/text()').getstringval() AS sap_id
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/SITE_NAME/text()').getstringval() AS site_name
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/RFCDATE/text()').getstringval() AS rfcdate
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/RFS_DATE/text()').getstringval() AS rfs_date
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/RFE1_DATE/text()').getstringval() AS rfe1_date
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/SITE_DROP_DATE/text()').getstringval() AS site_drop_date
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/INFRA_PROVIDER/text()').getstringval() AS infra_provider
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/IP_COLO_SITEID/text()').getstringval() AS ip_colo_siteid
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/VENDOR_CODE/text()').getstringval() AS vendor_code
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/MW_INSTALLED/text()').getstringval() AS mw_installed
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/DG_NONDG/text()').getstringval() AS dg_nondg
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/EB_NONEB/text()').getstringval() AS eb_noneb
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/TOWER_TYPE/text()').getstringval() AS tower_type
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE/text()').getstringval() AS id_od_countchange
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE/text()').getstringval() AS id_od_changeddate
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE/text()').getstringval() AS tenancy_countchange
                          ,strxml.extract('excelData/TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE/text()').getstringval() AS tenancy_changeddate
                      FROM TABLE(xmlsequence(strxml.extract('NewDataSet/excelData'))) strxml)
  LOOP
    null;
  END LOOP;

  cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  IF (cnt > 0)
  THEN
    BEGIN
      COMMIT;
      poutmsg := '1';
    END;
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      poutmsg := '0';

    END;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;

    poutmsg := '0';

END insert_expt_excel;
```

Comment: but I want to insert the xml data in my table.. if u want i can post the desc of table

Comment: i also added the insert statement and it got compiled.. is that OK ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way without using a FOR LOOP, which can lead to suboptimal performance as it is *row by row* approach 
would be to use `XMLTable` - see example below:

```
insert into tab (a,b)
with dt as (
select xmltype(
'<tab>
 <rec>
   <a>a1</a>
   <b>b1</b>
 </rec>  
 <rec>
   <a>a2</a>
   <b>b2</b>
 </rec> 
</tab>') col
from dual
)
select x.a,x.b 
from dt,
     XMLTable(
     'for $i in /tab/rec      
      return $i' 
      passing  (dt.col)
      columns
      a varchar2(5) path '//a',
      b varchar2(5) path '//b'
 ) x  
; 


select * from tab;

A     B    
----- -----
a1    b1   
a2    b2
```