# Wrong number or types of arguments when executing a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hope someone can help me, I've been getting this error but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I created this procedure that inserts the following information into a 'deposit' table for a bank: sequence number, personal number, account number, amount of deposit, and date). The procedure is also supposed to print out the total balance after the new deposit.

```
create or replace procedure do_insättning (
p_radnr kontoägare.radnr NUMBER(9),
p_pnr  bankkund.pnr VARCHAR(11), 
p_knr  konto.knr NUMBER(8), 
p_belopp  insättning.belopp NUMBER(10,2),
p_datum insättning.datum DATE,
p_saldo konto.saldo NUMBER(10,2))
is
begin
insert into kontoägare(radnr)
values(p_radnr);
insert into bankkund (pnr)
values(p_pnr);
insert into konto(knr)
values(p_knr);
insert into insättning(belopp)
values(p_belopp);
insert into insättning(datum)
values(sysdate);
insert into konto(saldo)
values(p_saldo);
commit;

dbms_output.put_line('Saldot är nu = ' || p_belopp + p_saldo);
end;
/
```

When I execute it this way, I get a wrong number of arguments error:

```
EXECUTE do_insättning (radnr_seq.NEXTVAL, '540126-1111', 123, 200, sysdate);
```

EDITED:

So I edited the query and tried to add saldo as a variable to be able to print the statement, but that didn't work either.

```
 create or replace procedure do_insättning (
      p_radnr  kontoägare.radnr%TYPE,
      p_pnr    bankkund.pnr%TYPE, 
      p_knr    konto.knr%TYPE, 
      p_belopp insättning.belopp%TYPE
    )
    is
    v_saldo konto.saldo%type;
    begin
    select saldo 
    into v_saldo
    from konto;
      insert into insättning(
        radnr,   pnr,   knr,   belopp,   datum
      ) values (
        p_radnr, p_pnr, p_knr, p_belopp, SYSDATE
      );
      dbms_output.put_line('Saldot är nu = ' || p_belopp + v_saldo);
    end;
    /
```

I get "numeric or value error: character to number conversion error".

Comment: you need to edit the question and show the types of each parameter.

Comment: Looks like you have 6 required parameters, you're only passing 5.

Comment: Edited the types for each!

Comment: @andrew The 6th parameter is the balance I needed to add the old balance and new deposit, to print out the total balance at the end of the procedure.

Comment: But Andrew is right, the procedure wants six parameters, the last parameter being p_saldo, but you call it with five parameters ending with the date (p_datum). Hence the DBMS rightfully complains that you are calling the procedure with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: So what? If you declared 6 parameters, you have to pass 6 parameters (as none of them has a DEFAULT value).

Comment: Ok. I removed the p_saldo parameter but now the error gives me ( cannot insert NULL into ("SQL_IMZEDKIAJKJEOBDJTOIVVHDFX"."KONTOÄGARE"."PNR")) I don't get it. Why does it say it's null when I'm adding a sequence as well as a declared parameter?

Comment: Ask a new question please.

Answer (score 2):

> I created this procedure that inserts the following information into a 'deposit' table for a bank

No, it does not insert the data into one table; it inserts it into four different tables (`kontoägare`, `bankkund`, `konto` and `insättning`) and creates 2 rows in each of the `konto` and `insättning` tables.

Your query is effectively:

```sql
create procedure do_insättning (
  p_radnr  kontoägare.radnr%TYPE,
  p_pnr    bankkund.pnr%TYPE, 
  p_knr    konto.knr%TYPE, 
  p_belopp insättning.belopp%TYPE,
  p_saldo  konto.saldo%TYPE
)
is
begin
  insert into kontoägare(radnr) values (p_radnr);
  insert into bankkund (pnr) values(p_pnr);
  insert into konto(knr, saldo) values(p_knr, NULL);
  insert into konto(knr, saldo) values(NULL, p_saldo);
  insert into insättning(belopp, datum) values(p_belopp, NULL);
  insert into insättning(belopp, datum) values(NULL, SYSDATE);
  COMMIT;
  dbms_output.put_line('Saldot är nu = ' || p_belopp + p_saldo);
end;
/
```

If you want to insert a single row into a single table (called `deposits`) then you want just a single `INSERT` statement:

```sql
create procedure do_insättning (
  p_radnr  kontoägare.radnr%TYPE,
  p_pnr    bankkund.pnr%TYPE, 
  p_knr    konto.knr%TYPE, 
  p_belopp insättning.belopp%TYPE,
  p_saldo  konto.saldo%TYPE
)
is
begin
  insert into deposits(
    radnr,   pnr,   knr,   saldo,   belopp,   datum
  ) values (
    p_radnr, p_pnr, p_knr, p_saldo, p_belopp, SYSDATE
  );

  dbms_output.put_line('Saldot är nu = ' || p_belopp + p_saldo);
end;
/
```

Then you can call it using:

```sql
EXECUTE do_insättning(
  p_radnr  => radnr_seq.NEXTVAL,
  p_pnr    => '540126-1111',
  p_knr    => 123,
  p_belopp => 200,
  p_saldo  => 42
);
COMMIT;
```

*Note: [don't put `COMMIT` statements in procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998025/what-is-the-effect-of-placing-the-commit-after-dml-in-procedure/41998936#41998936); `COMMIT` in the transaction that calls the procedure as that lets you chain multiple procedures together in a single transaction and apply a `ROLLBACK` statement to them all as a group.*

---

> When I execute it this way, I get a wrong number of arguments error:
>
> ```sql
> EXECUTE do_insättning (radnr_seq.NEXTVAL, '540126-1111', 123, 200, sysdate);
> ```

That is because your procedure takes 6 arguments and you have only provided 5.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! Now I got the procedure to work! But without the printed statement, cause the Saldo(balance) is not a column in the deposit table. So I'm supposed to take the value of saldo from the konto table and add that to the new belopp/balance and print it out as the new balance in the account!

Comment: I edited the question and added your solution.